# Convert String to Date Format - SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: string, date

I know this question has been asked more than a few times here however for some reason I just cant get the formula correct for my purposes.

I am pulling a 'year' from an external data source however it keeps formatting as (i.e. 2,016).

This is the formula I have so far but I cant seem to figure out how to put it together properly and format it as YYYY only.

```
formula = Year({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate})

Cstr({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate}, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

I am not qualified or experienced in coding whatsoever so have no idea how to put this together into a valid formula.

Thanks
Alicia

Answer (score 0):

The year is captured as  number and it is converted to 2,016
if 2016 is the data input 
use

```
ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate}, "yyyy")
```

if it is date use this

```
Examples (where Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate= January 15, 2011)
```

Example Result

```
ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate}, “yyyyMM”)   “201101?
ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate},”dd-MMM-yyyy”)   “15-Jan-2011?
ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate},”dd MMM yyyy”)   “15 Jan 2011?
ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate},”MM/dd/yy”)  “01/15/11?
ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate},”dddd, MMM d, yyyy”) “Saturday, Jan 1, 2011?
```

Comment: Thank you Jin. I think because I thought it was a String, when I right clicked on the field it wouldn't let me edit the number format. However I used ToText({Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate}, "yyyy") as you suggested above, and then I was able to edit the number format without the thousands separator.